# Back to top button - change fixed position based on resolution

Tags: css, layout, positioning

In [my site](http://webdev.aanm.ca/Evan_Parsons/Portfolio/index.aspx), the back to top button will follow the page, which is exactly what I want. However, if your resolution is above 1024x768 (which I'm pretty sure is the case for everyone) the button's position won't be inside the main content div.

I could use Javascript to detect the resolution, and then adjust the position from there, but if there's a cleaner solution, I'd prefer that! Also, I'm not a designer, so if anyone has any cosmetic input, it'd be appreciated!

Comment: Media queries? They could be what you need.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I think the button is quite cool over there! Now it's not in front of the text and it looks nice.

Comment: Can you roll back your code. Right now it is not at all scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution. Add a div to wrap the button.

```
<div id="button-wraper">
    <div id="backToTop">
            <a href="#top">
                <img src="site_resources/upArrow.png" style="border: none;z-index: 100;" alt="Back to top">
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#button-wraper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

And remove `position: fixed;` from `#backToTop`.

Also make sure to put this code just above `<div class="footer">` only.

Comment: I tried that, however it no longer scrolls with the page. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

Edit**

Try this:

```
<div id="button-wrap">
    <div id="backToTop">
        <a href="#top">
            <img src="site_resources/upArrow.png" style="border: none;z-index: 100;" alt="Back to top" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#button-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width:100%;
}

#backToTop {
  position:relative;
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #C6C6C6;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but then it won't scroll with the page?

Comment: Edited it, and it's almost like Libins example. wrap is now fixed -> always on bottom and then backToTop is formatted like content.. it should work

Comment: @Daniel Right now his page is not at all scrolling. I think he messed up the code. So I am not sure will this work or not.

Comment: But it doesn't have a smooth scroll. Its only jumping up.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<div id="backToTop">
            <a href="#top">
                <img alt="Back to top" style="border: none;z-index: 100;" src="site_resources/upArrow.png">
            </a>
        </div>
```

Inside the content div. Remove the "left" positioning and keep the bottom one, it would sit on its natural left position, since you don't have anything defined.

Actually, though, I think it looks much better where it is now.